# query without using subquery or explicit join

Tags: sql

I need to re-write this without using subquery and explicit join..help please been looking around for a while

```
SELECT snum, pnum, shipdate
FROM supply as b
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT pname, pnum FROM parts as a WHERE b.pnum = a.pnum);
```

Comment: What does that leave?  An implicit join?  You pretty need to have a `JOIN` or subquery to combine two tables.

Comment: I guess I need the implicit join but could you provide with an example? Been looking around and those examples were kinda weird

Comment: Why do you need to rewrite it? Is this an attempt at optimization? Or homework?

Comment: it is homework!

Comment: @Ara192 . . . The proper thing to do is to leave the question and accept the appropriate answer.  Removing the question like this is likely to lead to downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've been given a trick question. The answer is this.

```
SELECT snum, pnum, shipdate
FROM supply
```

The reason is that the condition you're checking for ***should be impossible in a well designed database***.

Let's have a look at what the original query is doing.

```
SELECT snum, pnum, shipdate
FROM supply as b
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT pname, pnum FROM parts as a WHERE b.pnum = a.pnum
);
```

It's getting every row in `supply` where there's a corresponding part in `parts`. How do you do this in a query without a join? You shouldn't have to do it in the first place. Instead you should rely on ***[referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)***.

Referential integrity is a property of good table design that says ***all references are valid***. There should be no need to check that each part in `supply` exists in `parts` because such a condition should be impossible. You do this with a well designed schema with appropriate use of foreign key and `not null` constraints.

(My examples are done in Postgres. The syntax for your database may vary.)

```
create table parts(
    pnum integer primary key,
    pname text not null
);

create table supply(
    snum integer primary key,
    pnum integer references parts(pnum) not null,
    shipdate date not null
);
```

By declaring `supply.pnum` as `references parts(pnum)` we have told the database this is a foreign key and there ***must*** be a corresponding row in `parts`. Adding `not null` guarantees each row in `supply` must supply a valid part. The database enforces these constraints automatically.

(Note that [MySQL takes a little more convincing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/) to enforce a foreign key constraint. Because MySQL is so non-standard one can pick up bad habits learning on it. Use Postgres or even SQLite instead.)

You can also add the constraints to an existing table using `alter table`.

```
test=> alter table supply alter pnum set not null;
ALTER TABLE
test=> alter table supply add constraint pnum_fk foreign key (pnum) references parts(pnum);
ALTER TABLE
```

For example, let's say we have these parts.

```
test=> select * from parts;
 pnum |  pname  
------+---------
    1 | flange
    2 | thingy
    3 | whatsit
```

We can insert a row into supply for one of those parts.

```
test=> insert into supply (pnum, shipdate) values (3, '2018-02-03');
INSERT 0 1
```

But if we try to insert a part that doesn't exist, we get an error.

```
test=> insert into supply (pnum, shipdate) values (99, '2018-02-03');
ERROR:  insert or update on table "supply" violates foreign key constraint "supply_pnum_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (pnum)=(99) is not present in table "parts".
```

Or one with a null part number...

```
test=> insert into supply (pnum, shipdate) values (null, '2018-02-03');
ERROR:  null value in column "pnum" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, 2018-02-03).
```

The condition you're testing for is now impossible. There's no need for it. So the answer is:

```
SELECT snum, pnum, shipdate
FROM supply
```

Comment: Yes, that may be the intention of this homework. Even better "smart optimizer" will skip `WHERE EXISTS` part entirely. More: [JOIN elimination](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/28/10-cool-sql-optimisations-that-do-not-depend-on-the-cost-model/#top3)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Yeah, it doesn't make much sense taken literally. The other answers are joins and subqueries in disguise.

Answer (score 0):

One way is `INTERSECT`(column list is limited to common ones):

```
SELECT pnum
FROM supply
INTERSECT
SELECT pnum
FROM parts;
```

---

Using [`SEMIJOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571665/5070879):

```
SELECT b.snum, b.pnum, b.shipdate
FROM supply as b
SEMIJOIN parts as a
   ON b.pnum = a.pnum;
```

Comment: An `intersect` is two subqueries appended together.

Comment: @Schwern INTERSECT are two independent queries(there is no [subquery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-2017)). With SET operators you don't have INNER/OUTER query.

Comment: To clarify, in Postgres it's implemented as two subqueries and I'm assuming it is in other databases as well. This is more a comment on the absurdity an exercise to rewrite a query without "subqueries" or "joins" because anything connecting two tables together is probably going to use those mechanisms. Bringing up set operators is a good one, they're too often forgotten.

Comment: @Schwern Still I could argue about definition of subquery. Depending or RDBMS you subquery could be sth different: for instance SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... FROM a) sub` is not a subquery but an inlined view. But let give up with semantics :)

Answer (score 0):

The subquery can be replaced by an INNER JOIN, as follows :

```
SELECT b.snum, b.pnum, b.shipdate
FROM 
    supply as b
    INNER JOIN parts as a ON b.pnum = a.pnum
GROUP BY b.snum, b.pnum, b.shipdate
```

You could also go for implicit join, but I would not recommend it as it is less readable and out of favor as of now :

```
SELECT b.snum, b.pnum, b.shipdate
FROM 
    supply as b,
    parts as a
WHERE b.pnum = a.pnum
GROUP BY b.snum, b.pnum, b.shipdate
```