# ActiveRecordy has_many through I need to find all parents where at least one child meet the condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three activerecord models:

the "A"

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_violation, class_name: "UserViolation", inverse_of: :user
  has_many :violations, through: :user_violation, class_name: "Violation"
end
```

the middle:

```rb
class UserViolation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
  belongs_to :violation, class_name: "Violation", foreign_key: :violation_id
end
```

the B:

```rb
class Violation < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I need to find all users who have AT LEAST one violation with column: `fatal` set to true.

Im kinda stuck here and this is not working:

```
User.joins(:violations).where('violations.fatal = true')
```

Comment: Is 'User.joins(:violation).where(violations: {fatal: 'true'})' working for you? I try to duplicate the issue to myself strangely violations relation on user is behaving like a belongs_to relation

Comment: It’s not working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To using query filter conditon in ORM I think this syntax should be:

```rb
User.joins(:violations).where(violations: {fatal: 'true'})
```

Comment: What is the error you encounter when running this command?

Comment: It’s just an empty record set

Comment: Is that result is wrong? Can you show me the plain where above by adding ‘.to_sql’ at the end of the query.

Comment: Maybe you should try:
`User.joins(violations: :user_violation).where(violations: {fatal: 'true'})`

Comment: Where there are multiple violations, this will return multiple User instances. 100,000 violations means you get the User 100,000 times.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Ninh Le's answer is right,(so did yours!) maybe you can simplify your models' code first to try to find where the problem is.
For example, I notice you missed the 's' in the has_many relation:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_violations
  has_many :violations, through: :user_violations
end

class UserViolation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :violation
end

class Violation < ApplicationRecord
  # has_many :user_violations
  # has_many :violations, through: :user_violations
end
```

I think it should work, if it's still not, check if there is record that has violation.fatal == true.

Then add the options of has_many, belongs_to if there 'really' needed.

Answer (score 0):

For the most efficient approach to finding these users, you'd want what the database people would call a ["semi-join"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249690/what-is-semi-join-in-database) - an exists subquery.

Assuming that "fatal" is defined by a `fatal` column having a value of `true`

```
User.
  where(
  Violation.
    where(fatal: true).
    joins(:user_violations).
    where(
      UserViolation.arel_table[:user_id].eq(User.arel_table[:id])
    ).arel.exists
  )
```

I'd suggest adding a scope to Violation that defines `fatal` without needing a where clause in that.