# SQL Query to find Records in Table1 that has one relation to Table2 but should have other relation to the same Table2

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have two tables for "Physical Location" and "Stores". One Physical Location can have multiple stores. Each Store can be either Active or Inactive.

How would we write a query to find those 'Physical Locations' that has no active Stores associated to it?

PhysicalLocation

```
LocationId    LocationAddress
100           Address1
101           Address2
102           Address3
```

Store

```
StoreID    LocationId        Status
100A           100           Active
100B           100           Inactive
101C           101           Inactive
102D           101           Inactive
```

I have tried something like the below.

```
Select * from PhysicalLocation where LocationId IN 
 (Select LocationId from Store where Status <> 'Active')
```

My expected result is

```
LocationId    LocationAddress
    101           Address2
```

Since this location has only inactive stores

Answer (score 2):

```
select l.LocationId,l.LocationAddress
from locations as l
where not exists
(
  select 1 from stores as s
    where l.LocationId=s.LocationId
     and s.Status='Active'
)
```

Could you please try this one if it is suitable for you.
By the way, location 102 also does not contain active stores

Answer (score 0):

Use `Joins`

```
SELECT * FROM PhysicalLocation 
INNER JOIN Store ON Store.LocationId = PhysicalLocation.LocationId
WHERE Store.Status = 'Inactive'
```

I have used `INNER JOIN` with the assumption that no store locations e.g `102 Address3`, is as good as the location with inactive store(s).

If the assumption is incorrect and you want all inactive along with locations where there are no stores, then go for `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have considered this. But this will give Physical locations, one of whose stores might be active also. Might not be in this result set.

Comment: @sqloverflow - so you need a query that should give a location only when all the stores in it are inactive?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Check @ggordon's answer. Its closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following which uses a having clause with a case expression in a count to filter out locations that have active stores. The join is used to retrieve additional location details.

```sql
SELECT
    P.*
FROM
   PhysicalLocation P
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT LocationId
   FROM Store
   GROUP BY LocationId
   HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Status='Active' THEN 1 END) =0
) SA ON p.LocationId=SA.LocationId
```

| LocationId | LocationAddress |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Address2 |

If you are interested in all locations with no active stores regardless of whether a store entry has ever been created then you may try the following which uses a left join and where clause to apply the filter instead of an inner join as above.

```sql
SELECT
    P.*
FROM
   PhysicalLocation P
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 
       LocationId,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Status='Active' THEN 1 END) as no_active_locations
   FROM Store
   GROUP BY LocationId
) SA ON p.LocationId=SA.LocationId
WHERE SA.no_active_locations=0 OR SA.no_active_locations IS NULL
```

| LocationId | LocationAddress |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Address2 |
| 102 | Address3 |

[View working demo db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=294d294b06dfa20aec07162c2f1b48bb)

Comment: Thank you @ggordon , this is close to what I was looking for. I learnt few things today !

Answer (score 0):

*The query will be like this.*

```
SELECT * FROM PhysicalLocation AS Ph INNER JOIN Store AS St ON Ph.LocationId = St.LocationId WHERE St.Status = 'Inactive';
```

Use Join to make relation between two tables. This is will give you resultant values you are looking for.

**Output:**

```
LocationId    LocationAddress    StoreID        LocationId    Status
100           Address1           100B           100           Inactive
101           Address2           101C           101           Inactive
101           Address2           102D           101           Inactive
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select what locations have active stores and filter out those locations in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT S.LocationId
    ,LocationAddress
FROM #Store S
    INNER JOIN #PhysicalLocation PL
        ON S.StoreID = PL.LocationId
WHERE S.LocationId NOT IN (SELECT LocationId FROM #Store WHERE [status] = 'active')
```

OUTPUT: [image]

This is slightly different than the desired output you specified, but I suspect you did not account for the additional address. There is still only 1 location with no active stores.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution :

```
select LocationId, LocationAddress from PhysicalLocation
where LocationId in 
(
    select Distinct (LocationId) from Store 
    where LocationId not in (select LocationId from Store where Status = 'Active')
)
```

Comment: Why `DISTINCT`, what purpose does it serve in a semi-join? And it's not a function, so why `(LocationId)`

Comment: Distinct will reduce list that we want to compare with. Without Distinct we will get same LocationId twice

Comment: You won't, because you're doing a semi-join with that `IN` clause, all it says is: are there any matching `LocationId` in the subquery, you don't need to `DISTINCT` the subquery

Comment: This is needed not because of the data query that we have in 'IN' clause but because the data that we have in Store table

Comment: Again `where LocationId in (select Distinct LocationId from Store` and `where LocationId in (select LocationId from Store` is *the same thing* because all it says is: are there *any* matches in the subquery, it makes no difference how many matches so you don't need to "reduce it down", it's not a join, it's a semi-join, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249690/what-is-semi-join-in-database