# insert if not present in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

The idea of this code was to insert new rows into a table after determining which "load_id"(s) are not present.

```
MERGE INTO stg.my_table AS tgt
using stg.my_view AS src
ON tgt. load_id = src.load_id
WHEN NOT matched THEN
  INSERT (id,
          document_type,
          state,
          publication_date,
          )
  VALUES (src.id,
          src.document_type,
          src.state,
          src.publication_date,
     );
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result without having to use a MERGE statement? Isn't an INSERT enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using  `INSERT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO stg.my_table  -- column list here
SELECT src.*
FROM stg.my_view AS src
LEFT JOIN stg.my_table AS tgt
  ON tgt.load_id = src.load_id
WHERE tgt.load_id IS NULL;
```

Also using `EXISTS`

```
INSERT INTO stg.my_table  -- column list here
SELECT src.*
FROM stg.my_view AS src
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM  stg.my_table AS tgt
                  WHERE tgt.load_id = src.load_id);
```

---

Extras:

Both patterns above are syntax that are executed as [ANTI-JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571665/5070879).

[image]

Comment: is there a performance difference between these 3 alternate solutions?

Comment: @x89 The differences if any should be negligible.  In any case you should always compare query profile and execution times.

Comment: @x89 IMO, `not exists` is a better solution because it communicates the intention of the code better AND also doesn't lead to duplicates that might result from a join when keys are not perfectly unique.

Comment: @Rajat `NOT EXISTS` is not necessarily  better solution than `LEFT JOIN WHERE tgt.join_col IS NULL`. The behaviour related duplicates is the same, if target contains  duplicates it will not produce duplicates, if source contains duplicates both will generate duplicate. [NOT EXISTS vs LEFT JOIN ... WHERE col IS NULL live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/t1d07vgF)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda You're correct about the the behavior of left join+null check implementation in your answer, although I would attribute that to the `where` clause rather than the `join`. I was making a broader point that `exists` doesn't cause "cross join by proxy" problem that `inner/left joins` are notorious for when datasets are duplicated on join key. `Exists` will retain existing duplicates, but won't add to that.

Comment: "-- column list here" i am guessing it is not essential to specify column names but is better for readability?

Comment: @x89 It is a good practice to explicitly state column list both in insert into and  avoid asterisk. `INSERT INTO trg(col1, col2,..) SELECT src.col1, src.col2, ...`